# Trouble with scraping <br> tag and datalist with links in it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is an example of the HTML I'm scraping with Python/Beautifulsoup:

```
<dl>
<dd>
    <strong>
        <a name="45790" href="http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45790">Monthly 18000rmb ESL teachers for Shanghai Webi centers</a>
    </strong>
    <br>
    Webi English Shanghai -- Tuesday, 7 March 2017, at 2:17 p.m.
</dd>

<dd></dd>
<dd></dd>
<dd></dd>
</dl>
```

I am able to scrape the `<a href>` but I haven't been able to get the text after the `<br>` despite running different loops.

This is my program:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

dl = soup.dl

ads = []

for words in dl.find_all('a'):
    links = words.get('href')
    link_text = words.text
    link_text = link_text.lower()

    if 'university' in link_text:
        ads.append([links, link_text])

    if 'universities' in link_text:
        ads.append([links, link_text])

    if 'college' in link_text:
        ads.append([links, link_text])

    if 'colleges' in link_text:
        ads.append([links, link_text])

for ad in ads:
    for job in ad:
        print(job)
        print("")
```

There is also a problem with duplicates being added to the list if the text contains more than one of my search terms, but I can deal with that later.

I'm thinking I want to have a list containing lists that hold the `link`, `link_text`, and `date_text`.

```
ads = [[link, link_text, date_text], [link, link_text, date_text]]
```

Right now, I can only get the link and link_text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [31]: for dd in soup.find_all('dd'):
    ...:     link = dd.a.get('href')
    ...:     link_text = dd.a.text
    ...:     *_, dd_text = dd.stripped_strings
```

out:

```
http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45391
Teach English in Shenyang, China: Great salary, Support, and Structured program
Greenheart Travel -- Thursday, 9 February 2017, at 1:05 p.m.
```

`dd_text` is the last text node of dd tag, so I use `*_` to represent all the text node before it.

EDIT:

```
In [20]: for dd in soup.find_all('dd'):
    ...:     
    ...:     d = {} # store data in a dict
    ...:     d['link'] = dd.a.get('href')
    ...:     d['link_text'] = dd.a.text
    ...:     *_, dd_text = dd.stripped_strings
    ...:     d['date_text'] = dd_text
    ...:     print(d)
```

out:

```
{'date_text': 'EnglishTeacherChina.com -- Sunday, 12 February 2017, at 1:45 '
              'p.m.',
 'link': 'http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45426',
 'link_text': '❤ ❤ ❤ Teach English In China 12,000-20,000 RMB/month - Adults '
              'or Kids - Free Housing & Airfare - Free TEFL TESOL '
              'Certification - Where You Want - YOUR NEEDS ARE OUR TOP '
              'PRIORITY ❤ ❤ ❤'}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had a little trouble implementing your suggestion.  I edited my question above if you have another minute to look at it.

Comment: @nasan you should use `dict` to store data, I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

you could use [contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents)

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<dl> .... </dl>') # your markup  
print(soup.br.contents[0])
```

gives:

```
Webi English Shanghai -- Tuesday, 7 March 2017, at 2:17 p.m.
```