# Scraping with Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Following on from [Beautifulsoup - trouble scraping datalist with links in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737517/beautifulsoup-trouble-scraping-datalist-with-links-in-it)

This is an example of the HTML I'm scraping with Python/Beautifulsoup:

```
<dl>
<dd>
    <strong>
        <a name="45933" href="http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45933">TOP RANKING UNIVERSITY SEEKS PROFESSIONAL LECTURERS</a>
    </strong>
    <br>
    Chongqing University -- Tuesday, 14 March 2017, at 6:58 a.m.
</dd>

<dd></dd>
<dd></dd>
<dd></dd>
</dl>
```

This is my program:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


def chinaJobs():
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/').read()

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

    ads = []

    for dd in soup.find_all('dd'):
        link = dd.a.get('href')
        link_text = dd.a.text
        link_text = link_text.lower()
        *_, dd_text = dd.stripped_strings

        if 'university' in link_text:
            ads.append([link, link_text, dd_text])

    for ad in ads:          
        for job in ad:
            print(job)
        print("")

chinaJobs()
```

I can get the information after the `<br>` tag, but it's the wrong information. This is the what the information on the website looks like:

> TOP RANKING UNIVERSITY SEEKS PROFESSIONAL LECTURERS
>
> > Chongqing University -- Tuesday, 14 March 2017, at 6:58 a.m.

This is what I would like my output to look like:

```
http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45933
top ranking university seeks professional lecturers
Chongqing University -- Tuesday, 14 March 2017, at 6:58 a.m.
```

This is what my output looks like:

```
http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45933
top ranking university seeks professional lecturers
EnglishTeacherChina.com -- Sunday, 12 February 2017, at 1:45 p.m.
```

This is printed with every output:

> EnglishTeacherChina.com -- Sunday, 12 February 2017, at 1:45 p.m.

Why do you think it is doing this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: How are you printing out the info after the br tag?

Comment: You could try getting everything inside the `dd` tag and splitting it by the `<br> `

Comment: @NoahCristino The first for loop saves the data into a list of lists with `[link, link_text, dd_text]`.  I thought the `dd_text` variable would be the info after the `<br>`.  They print out in the second for loop.

Comment: @NoahCristino I like the idea of just having two variables: text and link.  Can you show me how to split it at the `<br>`?

Comment: Have you checked what HTML your code is getting back because your code might be working but the website could be doing something wrong?

Comment: @chbchb55  "EnglishTeacherChina.com -- Sunday, 12 February 2017, at 1:45 p.m." is from the last entry at the bottom of the page.  So, it's grabbing that and printing it over and over.

Comment: @nasan First create another empty array (ex. place). Then under this: `*_, dd_text = dd.stripped_strings` you could do something like `brsplit = dd.decode_contents(formatter="html").split("<br>")`. Then that would make an array with everything before `<br>` in the first element and everything after in the second. So then just append it to the array like `place.append(brsplit[1]) `

Comment: Also you should change this: `if 'university' in link_text:` to this: `if 'university' in link_text.lower():`

Comment: @NoahCristino Do I append it in the `if statement` and then print both arrays in the second `for loop`?  Sorry, at my level, I would need to see the code to fully understand your comment.

Comment: @nasan do everything I told you right before the if and in the first for

Answer (score 0):

The string you are looking for is wrapped in the `<br>` tag, one option is to simply use `br` to extract it:

```
soup.find("dd").a.text
# u'TOP RANKING UNIVERSITY SEEKS PROFESSIONAL LECTURERS'

soup.find('dd').a.get("href")
# u'http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/index.cgi?read=45933'

soup.find('dd').br.text.strip()
# u'Chongqing University -- Tuesday, 14 March 2017, at 6:58 a.m.'
```

You can try change the `dd_text` line to `dd_text = dd.br.text.strip()`.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape all the job ads that have 'university' in them.  Would I put your suggestion into a for loop to do this?

Comment: Yes, replace the ddtext line in the for loop.

Comment: for dd in soup.find_all('dd'):
        link = dd.a.get('href')
        link_text = dd.a.text
        dd_text = dd.br.text.strip()     That works to get the `<br>` tag, but then my `if statement` doesn't work, and the output has jobs that don't have 'university' in them.  Thanks though.

Comment: `link_text = dd.a.text.lower()` link text still has to be lowered.